# Deleting a Node from a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm trying to delete a given Node from a Linked List. I don't know why my code is not working. Any hints?
So I have [11,21,31,41] and they are asking me to delete the node at index 2 in this case 31. So far I have this:

```
public void delete (int k) {
    //[ 11 21 31 41 ].delete( 2 ): expected=[ 11 21 41 ]
    if (k < 0 || k >= N) throw new IllegalArgumentException ();

    for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
        //deletes node
        if(x.item == k){
            x = x.next;
        }
        if(x.item <= k){
            x = x.next.next;
        }
    }


}
```

Can someone tell me please why is this not working? Thank you

Comment: What is the error you getting? Or is it just not removing the element.

Comment: it's not removing the element at all...

Comment: You need to set next of your previous node to next of the node you want to delete (assuming a singly linkedlist)

Comment: Why do you think it will work?

Answer (score 0):

You could move nodes using next `k` times.  Store a temporary int and a previous node.  Decrement the temporary int each time you call `next()`.  Once you are at 0 (the desired element), remove by setting the previous node's next pointer to x's next pointer, and then set `x` to `null`.

I think in your code you are missing the part where pointers are set.

For example:

```
(1) -> (2) -> (3)
```

To remove `(2)`, set `(1).next = (3)` and `(2) = null`.  This will get:

```
(1) -> (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going wrong here, and I encourage you to work on some println debugging to better understand the issues as you develop.

1. Assuming the `item` field is the value of the Node, you're comparing that value of a Node to the index of said Node (e.g. `x.item == k`).
2. The general logic that you're going to want to follow is, "if the Node the iterator is pointing to is the next Node in my list, set my `next` to its `next`."

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are comparing the value of node with the index you passed. This comparison will always have index less than value in node. Also after that you are not updating the node when you assume the code is correct.

Below code should give you the result.

```
public void delete (int k)
{
//[ 11 21 31 41 ].delete( 2 ): expected=[ 11 21 41 ]
if (k < 0 || k >= N) throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
int count = 0;//Assuming index starts from 0
Node prev;
for(Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
{
    //deletes node
    count++;
    if(count<k)
    {
        prev = x;
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        prev.next = x.next;
        x.next = null;
        break;
    }

}
if(count>k || count<k)
{
    System.out.println("No element with index k");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@vase is correct saying

> Assuming the item field is the value of the Node, you're comparing
>   that value of a Node to the index of said Node (e.g. x.item == k).

some example code that could fix this

```
public void delete(int k){
   Node n = first;
   for(int i = 0; i < k-1; i++){ // this loop finds the node right before the 
   n=n.next;                    // index to use to delete the desired index.
}
   n.next = n.next.next; // delete command
}
```